# Why aren't props updated as state is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing the state of a component into another component as a prop. When that state is updating, it doesn't seem to be updating the corresponding prop.

I've tried a number of things, such as putting this in the return function and updating the "lower" components state as the prop but nothing seems to be working.

This is the constructor function

```
class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(); 
        this.state = {
            testing:false,
            hitWall:false,
            outTime:false,
            outBounds:false,
            youWon:false

        }
        this.maze=[]
    }
```

This is where the state gets updated:

```
    attemptMaze = () => {
        this.setState({
            testing:true
        })
    }
```

This where I'm building the thing with that event listener:

```
      return (
          <div className="holderDiv">
        <div onMouseOver={(this.state.testing) ? this.outOfBounds:undefined} className="outOfBounds"></div>
        <div onMouseOver={(this.state.testing) ? this.outOfBounds:undefined} className="outOfBoundsTwo"></div>
        <div onMouseOver={(this.state.testing) ? this.outOfBounds:undefined} className="outOfBoundsThree"></div>
        <form onSubmit={this.state.testing?this.handleSubmit:undefined}>
        <button onClick = {this.state.testing?this.submitMaze:this.didntStart} type="submit" className="finishMaze" style={{'display':this.state.submitShowing}}>Submit Maze</button>
        <div className="grid">
        {this.state.maze}
        </div>
        </form>

        <button type="submit" onClick={this.attemptMaze} className="startEndButton" style = {{'fontSize':'30px'}}>Attempt Maze</button>
        <h1 className="displayName">{this.state.name}</h1>
        <TimerTwo />
        </div>
```

This is where I am building the "lower" component (the square)

```
getMaze = async (e) => {
        const mazeResponse = await fetch(`/maze/test/${this.props.match.params.testId}`)

        const parsedResponse = await mazeResponse.json();
        console.log(parsedResponse.data,'<----parsedResponse.data')
        testMaze = parsedResponse.data.maze;
        testName = parsedResponse.data.name
        console.log(testMaze)
        this.setState({
            name:testName,
            maze:
            testMaze.map((element)=>{
            return <div><Square hit ={this.hit} testing={this.state.testing} className="cell" color={element=="1"?'black':null} style={{'height':'5px','width':'5px','backgroundColor':element==1?'black':'white','margin':0}}></Square></div>
        }
        )
    })

    }
```

And this is where I am rendering the lower component

```
render(){
        return(
            <div className="boxes" onMouseOver = {this.props.testing?this.switchColor:undefined} style={{'height':'5px','width':'5px','backgroundColor':this.state.color,'margin':'0'}}>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I cannot seem to make it so that switchColors runs when the "testing" is true and not run when "testing" is false. It's the final bug I can't seem to manage on this project. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your page reload as a normal form submit when the `button` is pressed ?

Comment: No it's not reloading, but I through an e.preventDefault to make sure and it still doesn't work, thanks though

Comment: did you try using [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) life cycle method inside Square?

Comment: it won't update if you are  saving `this.props.testing` in state in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try replacing `button type="submit"` with `button type="button"` to avoid any unwanted form submissions.
2. Include a `console.log` statement in all your event handlers to make sure they are getting called. It's possible you have a typo for the react event property or for the event handler.